# ETL with CRM Dynamics 365 in azure

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We have CRM Dynamics 2015 onsite. The CRM Developer provided us with a proxy we can connect to to insert and extract data to/from CRM, which we connect to via  SSIS script component to extract data from this for downstream systems and data warehouses.

There are plans to migrate to Dynamics 365 SAAS. I want to be sure that we have a plan for how to continue inserting/extracting data via ETL into Dynamics 365.

Besides running SSIS in an Azure VM, are there any services or alternatives within Azure that might be a  better option for ETL with Dynamics 365?

Comment: You can have Scribe in Azure VM, Did you explore?

Comment: How does your Proxy Connect to Dynamics CRM? If it use Standard Dynamics API you can leave your ETL Process on Premise.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which api your on prem tool is using you could just change the connection string to point to CRM Online. If that doesn't work either use [scribe](https://www.scribesoft.com/) or use [Kingswaysoft's SSIS tools](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365) to provide that integration.